# Application_Error() doesn't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 Application and I'm trying to capture any uncaught errors. To do this I have created a method in Global.asax.cs as follows:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    MyLogger.Log("some text");
}
```

When I run the project locally, this method gets triggered for 404's, 500's, etc.. However, the moment I switch the application to Release and I put it on the server, it handles 404's, but no longer handles 500's. I have created a method to throw an error such as this:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public string Error()
{
    var s = int.Parse("hello abc 123");

    return "Hello World";
}
```

The method ofcourse crashes as it can't convert the text to int, but Application_Error() does not triggers. If I try to visit a page that doesn't exist, it triggers and I can see it in the logs.

I have looked at web.config, and in production this is the setting:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Index"></customErrors>
```

Also, in filter.config I have:

```
filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
```

if I comment that line above, my Application_Error activates and I can see the log. However, the page no longer redirects to my custom error page. Instead, I get a white screen with the following message:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

My question is:

Why does the website stops handling 404 errors when I put the website in production with the above web.config setting. How can make it capture those errors?

EDIT: I have boiled down the problem to this: If I comment out HandleError attribute then my Application_Error() method fires off. If I put it back in, it does not. On my local machine it works always, when I push it to azure, it stops working.

Comment: Why not simply generate an error with: throw new Exception(...)

Comment: You get more debug output if you use a browser on the server, i.e, locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HandleError attribute will trigger and as a result the Application_Error will not. As HandleException is part of the MVC pipeline, it will handle the error and prevent it from being thrown. The reason this has been working locally for me is I had `debug="off"` in web.config.

So my solution is to either not use HandleError exception, or to write a custom one that extends and also logs.